# Can't access Windows Partition anymore - No permissions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, permissions

I've installed Ubuntu 15.10 alongsite Windows 10. I was able to access Windows partition without any problems since today, after rebooting my compyter I can't access it anymore.

A pop-up shows up saying "Impossible to show the content this position. Not enough privileges to see the content of ...".

I haven't modified anything about the partition, why this problem shows up now randomly?

I use this options to mount the disk [image]

Update: It seems to be a problem with managing NTFS partitions. I've tried to plug my external HDD and I'm able to read-only, can't write on it.

Comment: Is the UUID still the same? you can check it with "lsblk -fs"

Comment: Yes, still 1810CB1810CAFC2E. Never changed.

Comment: The screenshot shows that the auto mount option is off. I guess that you've turned that to ON...

Comment: Have you try remounting the partition <code>sudo mount -o remount,rw /partition/identifier /mount/point</code>.. this will try to remount the partition in read/write mode. Enter your mount point and partition identifier (something like sdb , sdc ...) Saluti!

Answer (score 0):

You are mounting this drive on a subfolder of `/mnt`. Your user must have read (`r`) and (`x`) permissions on both the subfolder and `/mnt`. However, resetting ownership of `/mnt` is not recommended.

To avoid this issue, I would recommend you mount your drive on a subfolder of your `home` directory (`/home/username/ntfs`).

Comment: Didn't changed anything. Still have the same permissions problem..

Comment: Is ntfs-3g installed?